# NotFittedError issue with Sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use the LinearSVC of sklearn and export the decision tree to a .dot file. I can fit the classifier with sample data and then use it on some test data but the export to the .dot file gives a NotFittedError.

```
data = pd.read_csv("census-income-data.data", skipinitialspace=True, usecols=list(range(0, 41)))
data = data.fillna('Missing value').apply(pp.LabelEncoder().fit_transform)

target = pd.read_csv("census-income-data.data", skipinitialspace=True, usecols=[41])

dataTest = pd.read_csv("census-income-test.test", skipinitialspace=True, usecols=list(range(0, 41)))
dataTest = dataTest.fillna('Missing value').apply(pp.LabelEncoder().fit_transform)

targetTest = pd.read_csv("census-income-test.test", skipinitialspace=True, usecols=[41])
clfSVC = LinearSVC(random_state=0)

clfSVC = clfSVC.fit(data, target.target)
scoreSVC = clfSVC.score(dataTest, targetTest.target)
print(scoreSVC)
tree.export_graphviz(clfSVC, out_file='tree.dot')
```

Here is the output:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\Telecom\IA\ai-person-income\project\sklearn_test.py", line 49, in <module>
    tree.export_graphviz(clfSVC, out_file='tree.dot')
  File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\export.py", line 392, in export_graphviz
    check_is_fitted(decision_tree, 'tree_')
  File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 768, in check_is_fitted
    raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This LinearSVC instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a [function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html#sklearn-tree-export-graphviz) to plot a decision-tree. Look at the first argument: *decision_tree*, like an object of [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html).

A SVM is not a decision-tree! It isn't any kind of tree and you can't use this function and it also makes no sense in theory.

The error itself is based on [this code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/tree/export.py#L392):

```
check_is_fitted(decision_tree, 'tree_')
```

where the internal tree of a decision-tree object is queried. This does not exists for SVMs.

Answer (score 1):

In `sklearn.tree.export_graphviz`, the first parameter is a fitted decision tree.
You give a fitted estimator, but not a decision tree.
**Indeed, `LinearSVC` is not a decision tree.**

Try with `sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier` instead of `sklearn.svm.LinearSVC`.